# Copy over datagrid values in column 1 and 2 to new form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid of 2 columns in Form1 - and when I user double clicks on a particular cell (in either one of the two columns), I want the data from the two columns in that respective row to be copied over to Form2 (textBox1 and textBox2).

How can I accomplish this?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form2 = newForm2();
    Form2.Show()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is wpf not winforms?

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn - question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CurrentRow` property (I'm assuming they're both strings):

```
var selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;

var cellOneValue = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
var cellTwoValue = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[1].Value);
```

You can also use column names, which is easier to read and maintain:

```
var cellOneValue = Convert.ToString(d.Cells["nameOfYourColumn"].Value);
```

Then pass it to `Form2` via public properties or the constructor itself:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(cellOneValue, cellTwoValue);
```

Then accept it in the other form:

```
public Form2(string someValue, string anotherValue)
{
    // Do something with passed values... might want to name these better ;)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - how would this fit into the context of what I'm doing. Where would I put it in? I've also noticed that one value is being pulled - how would I go about pulling the second value in the second column?

Comment: Thanks - what should I do with the message `The name "d" does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I've done the following - `private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            var cell1 = Convert.ToString(d.Cells[0].Value);
            var cell2 = Convert.ToString(d.Cells[1].Value);
            newForm();
        }`